# how do I make an element a child of itself in XML Schema?

Tags: xml, schema, nested

I'd like the ability to have an arbitrary level of nesting children of the same parent element, e.g.:

```
<path expr="/">
  <path expr="usr">
    <path expr="bin">
      <path expr="X11" />
    </path>
  </path>
  <path expr="var" />
</path>
```

I'm writing the XML Schema file, and I'm at a loss as to how to represent this parent/child relationship in the schema:  here's what I have, but it's not a valid schema definition:

```
          <xs:element name="path">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="path" minOccurs="0" />
              </xs:sequence>
              <xs:attribute name="expr" type="xs:string" use="required" />
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
```

Update:  Thanks for the response. I tried that, and I'm getting the following error: The 'w3.org/2001/XMLSchema:complexType' element is not supported in this context. I should mention that the path hierarchy as I've described is itself a child of an element called application, so the entire structure resembles this:

```
<application name="test">
  <path expr="/">
    <path expr="usr">
      <path expr="bin">
        <path expr="X11" />
      </path>
    </path>
    <path expr="var" />
  </path>
</application>
```

Answer (score 5):

The following should do the trick. 
The XSD standard is pretty difficult to work with directly, I always use an editor like [Liquid XML Studio](http://www.liquid-technologies.com/XmlStudio/Free-Xsd-Editor.aspx).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!--Created with Liquid XML Studio - Developer Pro Edition 7.1.1.1206 (http://www.liquid-technologies.com)-->
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="Path" type="PathType" />
  <xs:complexType name="PathType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Path" type="PathType" />
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="expr" type="xs:string" use="required" />
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

[image]
<sub>(source: [liquid-technologies.com](http://www.liquid-technologies.com/images/blogs/stackoverflow/PathExample.png))</sub>

The XSD is valid. For the new XML you described you would need to change it to look like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!--Created with Liquid XML Studio - Developer Pro Edition 7.1.0.1135 (http://www.liquid-technologies.com)-->
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="Application">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="path" type="PathType" />
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:complexType name="PathType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="path" type="PathType" />
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="expr" type="xs:string" use="required" />
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I tried that, and I'm getting the following error:

The 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema:complexType' element is not supported in this context. 

I should mention that the path hierarchy as I've described is itself a child of an element called application, so the entire structure resembles this:

<application name="test">
  <path expr="/">
    <path expr="usr">
      <path expr="bin">
        <path expr="X11" />
      </path>
    </path>
    <path expr="var" />
  </path>
</application>

Comment: @Nick Davis: It's best to add clarifications like this one to the question itself (you can always edit it). In a comment you don't have formatting, and potentially important details are out of view.

Comment: Thanks for the tip -- I've edited the original question with my comment.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I prefer [RelaxNG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RelaxNG) over XML Schema. May be worth your time to try it out.